# change style class onclick, based on radio group click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm struggling to solve simple script: I would like to change an `<li>` item css class when radio button clicked. I've created an onclick event and passing 2 parameters to the function 'setColor'. Then in the function I concatenate the .style with the value of radio button clicked. So far I've got the following:

```
function setColor(a, b){
    document.getElementByTd("id").setAttribute('.STYLE' + a);    
}
```

My items generated dynamically from the db package, same as styles. I would like to apply the 'correct' style when users click on the radio button. But unfortunately, I've got the error : "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByTd'". Confused and already spent hours and hours to identify the problem ... must be something very simple, but cannot figure out. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There's no native `.getElementByTd()` method.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo in your question, but you have `getElementByTd`

Comment: ooops, thanks for that, didn't noticed ! however, it didn't solved the problem, but I'm close ...

Comment: $('li#someID').addClass('someClass');

Comment: $('li#someID.someClass').removeClass('someClass');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript `onChange` event to call a function to change a CSS DOM style.  I would probably do it like this:

```js
function setColor(a){
    document.getElementById("color").style.background = a;    
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="color" onchange="setColor(this.value)" value="red"/> Red</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="color" onchange="setColor(this.value)" value="blue"/> Blue</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="color" onchange="setColor(this.value)" value="green"/> Green</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="color" onchange="setColor(this.value)" value="yellow"/> Yellow</label>

<div id="color" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! however it doesn't solved completely my issue, but getting much closer!